# Grunt generate ipa and apk

Tags: gruntjs, ipa, hybrid-mobile-app

We have a hybrid application which is developed for platforms Android and iOS. We have written our own wrappers and thus not using PhoneGap. Do we have any grunt submodules which generate ipa and/or apk ?

Comment: Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-crosswalk

Comment: @Vishwanath i checked crosswalk, but its not building. see some support ticket open in that regard, if you have used it can you pls put more light on it ?